# Does Sitecore eLearning training course contain certification coupon?

Tags: sitecore-commerce, support, training

Compared to the instructor led training if I purchase an eLearning module and want to appear for examination , does 1500$ cost include the one time certification coupon ?

Can I get Sitecore support if I land into some difficulties during eLearning training ?

What about Sitecore Commerce training?
Will Sitecore® Experience Commerce™ 9 300 exam be launched on eLearning platform ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes at the end of the training you will receive certification coupon.

On https://elearning.sitecore.net/Public/ContentDetails.aspx?id=BC286B8A482C49BD8CB52CE507B666D0  is described what it contains the training.

**The purchase of the Sitecore® Platform Essentials for Developers eLearning includes the option to take the Sitecore® Certified Platform Associate Developer exam**. Developers who pass the exam become Sitecore® Certified Professionals. Developers can register to take the exam with an online proctored service from anywhere in the world or at a testing center.

You will not get any help from Sitecore if you have issue during elearning training.

Regarding last question (Sitecore® Experience Commerce™ 9 300 on elearning) I suggest to ask Sitecore from your region.

If you have more questions I suggest you to send mail to  one of the bellow:

North and South America:  **ustraining@sitecore.net**

Europe, Middle East, Africa: **training-emea@sitecore.net**

Greater Asia: **training-apac@sitecore.net**

Japan: **training.jp@sitecore.net**

Australia, New Zealand: **training-au@sitecore.net**

Comment: This answer is quite out of date at this point. For the newer certifications, the test taker makes the purchase directly from Kryterion. It is not included in any of the newer elearning (e.g., the CDP Developer Deep Dive, Order Cloud developer course, etc.)